# Node - FTP - Get and Restart

Tags: node.js, stream, ftp, restart

I created an FTP application that works well.
I can upload and download. I display the progression.
I can resume a upload but...
I have an issue to resume a download.

I use this code to restart a download.

```
// When Connection Ready
clientFtp.on('ready', function(){

    // Source and Destination determination
    var serverFile  = "example_file_on_server.zip";
    var localFile   = "example_file_on_client.zip";

    // List Remote File
    clientFtp.list(serverFile,function(erreurListage, serverElementList) {

        // Get Total File Weight
      serverFileSize = serverElementList[0].size;

        // Get Local File Info
        localFileInfo   = fs.statSync(localFile);
        let restartSize = localFileInfo.size;

        // Forcing for Restart from...
        clientFtp.restart(restartSize,function(erreurRedemarrage){

            // Initialization
            tailleDownload = restartSize;

            // Get File
            clientFtp.get(serverFile, function(erreurRecuperation, stream) {


            stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFile, {flag:'r+',start: restartSize}));

            stream.on('data',function(buffer){

                        tailleDownload          = buffer.length+tailleDownload;
                        pourcentageDownload =   (tailleDownload/serverFileSize*100).toFixed(0);

                        console.log(pourcentageDownload);
        });

            

            });
        });
    });         
});
```

I must specify that the code used for reading the download stream works well without restarting.
But when I use it with restart, I have a file with a good size but not readable (it's a zip file). The file seems corrupted.

Note : I use r+ flag and restart but I use them correcty...?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question and I begin with : RTFM !!!
Why...? Because it's **flags** for options and **not flag**

I continue with this information.
Don't use start in createWriteStream.
If you use restart on FTP connection, you don't need to put start option in createWriteStream.

This code works fine

`stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFile,{flags: 'a'}));`